# FragmentStatePagerAdapter: Don' t load all Tabs at the beginning

Tags: android, tabs, fragmentpageradapter

In my Android app I use tabs with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I have many tabs, so it is a problem, that the FragmentStatePagerAdapter calls the onCreateView-method for all of them when the app starts. This is completely useless, because the method is called again, when I open a tab. Is there a way to prohibit that the onCreateView-method is called for all tabs at the beginning (It should only be called for the current tab and the tab left and right from it)?

Answer (score 0):

> that the FragmentStatePagerAdapter calls the onCreateView-method for all of them when the app starts

`ViewPager` will load 2-3 pages when it handed its `PagerAdapter`. Other pages will only be created when the user changes pages. `ViewPager` itself ensures that there is a page to either side of the current page (except for either end of the range of pages).

> This is completely useless, because the method is called again, when I open a tab

`onCreateView()` will only be called when the fragment is created or when a configuration change occurs (e.g., screen rotation). `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` only hold onto a certain number of pages, so if the user swipes around a lot, `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` will discard existing fragments and, eventually, re-create them if the user returns to them in the future.

> Is there a way to prohibit that the onCreateView-method is called for all tabs at the beginning

It already behaves this way by default.

For example, if you take [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments), change it to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, and add `Log.e()` calls to `onCreateView()` of the `EditorFragment`, you will see two `onCreateView()` calls when the `ViewPager` is initially displayed, plus an additional call on every swipe that requires a fragment instance to be created.